# ValidationError: 'value' is not a valid binding on <textField> elements Svelte-Native

Tags: svelte-native

I've created a new Svelte-native application and I'm trying to bind my value as follows:

```
<script lang="ts">
  let newItem = ''
</script>

<page>
  <actionBar title="Svelte Native App" />
  <flexboxLayout flexDirection="column">
    <textField bind:value={newItem} />
  </flexboxLayout>
</page>
```

The problem is, when I run this application I get the following error:

> ValidationError: 'value' is not a valid binding on  elements

I'm not sure how to solve this, my IDE (VSCode) also returns a svelte invalid binding error.